# The Animation is not showing

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm trying this very simple code. It runs but doesn't show the animation. I'm new to animations, so I don't know what I'm missing.

```
package sample;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Sample extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, Velx = 5;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, 30, 50, 50);
        tm.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = x + Velx;
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample X = new Sample();
        JFrame a = new JFrame();
        a.setTitle("Rectangle RED");
        a.setSize(500,500);
        a.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sample X = new Sample();
```

`X` is never added to the frame.  See first tip (the **bold** part) for how to add `X` to the frame.

Other tips:

- `Sample` should `@Override` the `getPreferredSize()` method to return a sensible size for the canvas. Then we can dispense with `a.setSize(500,500);` and instead **`a.add(X); a.pack();`** to get the frame to be the exact right size to display the rendering.
- The `Timer` should be started in some place other than the paint methods! I'd go for the constructor.
- Custom painting in any `JComponent` should be done in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.
- In all custom painting, we should immediately call the `super` method to ensure that previous drawings are erased by painting the BG and border of the container.
- Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.
- `JFrame a = new JFrame(); a.setTitle("Rectangle RED");` could be shortened to
   `JFrame a = new JFrame("Rectangle RED");`